# How to add env vars into k8s job.yaml dynamically?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, yq, kubernetes-jobs

I have store my env vars in aws secret manger.In CD pipeline I will read this env from secret manager and store into env.yaml once it is available in env.yaml,i want to render it to kubernetes job.yaml file. How to render env var from env.yaml to my k8s job.yaml ??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your `env.yaml` structure is however i would suggest adding the secret as the **kubenetes** secret.

You can mount the secret to any job running into the K8s.

If you want to parse it from one YAML to add it into the another YAML file you can use the tool [Yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq#readme) to parse the values.

Example:

```
---
maindata:
  data1:
    name: jack
  data2:
    name: reacher
```

run command

```
yq eval '.maindata.*.name' env.yaml
```

will output

```
- jack
- teacher
```

You can save output or write it to variable and use it.

Comment: My env.yaml structure is same as kubernetes env key.  If I use secret then still I had to render it from secret manager. can you share yq command snippet with job.yaml example.

Comment: you already mentioned you are storing secret to env.yaml just apply it to k8s and use secret in job spec simply with name only.

Comment: Sorry miscommunication from my side. My env vars are stored in AWS secret manager. When I run cd pipeline i will read this env from secret manager and store into env.yaml

Comment: got that. now if you are storing it inside the env.yaml you can either parse it or apply file to k8s so it will create the secret inside k8s cluster. You can inject the secret to Job.